# How to get currently opened file's project folder path in visual studio code extension.js

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to get currently opened file's project folder path in visual studio code extension but not working for Multi-root Workspaces.

Now i am getting path value is empty.

Currently i opened project-ws folder files app.component.html then press ctrl+shift+p on the files tab then box will open. if i click "Get project folder path" from extension box path value should be like C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\project-ws.

If i opened project-bh folder any files then press ctrl+shift+p on the files tab then box will open. if i click "Get project folder path" from extension box path value should be like C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\project-bh.

I could not find the mistake from my code.Anyone can resolve this issue?

Check this url then you can test in your vs code extension you can easily understand : https://github.com/jasonnutter/vscode-search-node-modules
same concept i have used from this for my extension.

[image].

Press Ctrl+Shift+p = to see extension and click "Get project folder path" then path message should be come.

[image]

C:/Users/ADMIN/.vscode/extensions/getprojectpath/extension.js:

```
  const vscode = require('vscode');
  const path = require('path');
  exports.activate = context => {

  const searchMyModules = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.search', () => {

  const preferences = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('files.exclude');

  const getCurrentlyopenedtabprojectfolderpath = async() => {

  const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
  if (!editor || !vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders || vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders.length < 2) {
    return null;
  }
  let path;
  const resource = editor.document.uri;
  if (resource.scheme === 'file') {
    const folder = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(resource);
    if (!folder) {
      path = `$(alert) <outside workspace> → ${basename(resource.fsPath)}`;
    } else {
      path = `$(file-submodule) ${basename(folder.uri.fsPath)} (${folder.index + 1} of ${vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders.length}) → $(file-code) ${basename(resource.fsPath)}`;

    }
  }
  return {
    path
  };
}

 getCurrentlyopenedprojectpath().then(result => {
  vscode.window.showInformationMessage(result.path)
 })
 })
 }

 exports.deactivate = () => {};
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how this code is not working?  What does it print, and which file are you testing it with?  Also, it would be easier to help if the code were [smaller and self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have edited my question.Please check it.

Comment: @Scott McPeak: Which line I want to change from my script to get correct output?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.  I appreciate the edits you've made to try to clarify the question, but the code still is still more complicated than it needs to be to demonstrate just the behavior of `getWorkspaceFolder`.  Have you tried stepping through this code line by line in the debugger?  If so, exactly what path does the flow of execution follow?  Can you remove all of the code that is not executed?

Comment: Simple.. Go to this link https://github.com/jasonnutter/vscode-search-node-modules  then download it. Then place this folder in your vs code extension path. Then do it npm install for this folder. After that open extension.js then remove all scripts then paste my script. Then press ctrl+shift+p   box will open then click this extension like search node modules then see what message is coming

Comment: Please help me.. I am trying from the past one month

Comment: Those are useful instructions for someone to reproduce the problem; I suggest adding them to the question.  But you're still unlikely to find someone who will do that much work to answer an SO question; I won't (sorry).  If you can make a *minimal* reproducer, someone might help.  Follow the link in my first comment.

Comment: OMG..So too sad

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822840/how-to-get-path-for-currently-open-tab-files-root-path

Answer (score 0):

You can try `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders` and `vscode.workspace.workspaceFiles`. These will return a list of files and folders of the currently opened directory