# How to get path for currently open tab file's root path

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Tried to get project folder path in multi root workspace condition in visual studio code but facing very difficult to find the path.
Below script only will work  single root workspace But How to change for multi root workspace.

```
var vscode = require("vscode");
var path = require("path");
exports.activate = context => {
const searchoption = 
vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.search', () => {

   let folderPath = vscode.workspace.rootPath; // get the open file's project folder path

});
}
```

Comment: from all open workspace folders try to match the one that starts your current active file (`string.startsWith`).

Comment: found this link in the 1.38 release notes https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Adopting-Multi-Root-Workspace-APIs#eliminating-rootpath

Answer (score 3):

Instead of [`workspace.rootPath`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.rootPath), use [`workspace.workspaceFolders`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.workspaceFolders) to get all of the folders.

But the title of your question refers to the "currently open tab".  That isn't a meaningful concept in the `activate` function, which only runs when the extension first initializes.  You'll want to instead write, say, a command handler (see the [extension tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension)), and within that handler, use [`window.activeTextEditor`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.activeTextEditor), and eventually call [`window.getWorkspaceFolder`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.getWorkspaceFolder).

Comment: Example : You opened many projects in your vs code then how you can identify which file from which project?

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is not to get others to do your work for you.  You should attempt to solve this yourself using the provided information before asking for more help.